# SQL : Max (), Groupby

Tags: sql

So I have a table with columns MapID, CityFrom, CityTo and  Distance and I want to get the the cities with the maximum distance travelled from each `MapID`. One `MapID` contains multiples cities and distances in itself.

-The below query gives me max distances per each `MapID` but when I try to add
columns `CityFrom` and `CityTo` it gives the whole table:

```
 SELECT R.MapID, Max(R.Distance) 'Length'
 FROM    ROAD R
 GROUP BY R.MapID
```

-Adding `CityFrom` and `CityTo` (whole table with `96` rows)

```
SELECT    R.*, Max(Distance)
FROM      ROAD R
GROUP BY  R.MapID, R.IDFRom,  R.IDTo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT r.* 
FROM (SELECT r.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY R.MapId ORDER BY R.Distance DESC) as seqnum
      FROM road r
     ) r
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear your schema definition is complete, but you can join your grouped query to another table to get the scalar values for that row.

Assuming `IDFRom` is `CityFrom` and `IDTo` is what you have listed as `CityTo`:

```sql
SELECT 
    grouped.MapID, 
    grouped.[Length], 
    R.IDFRom as CityFrom, 
    R.IDTo as CityTo
FROM
 (
  SELECT R.MapID, Max(R.Distance) [Length]
   FROM   ROAD R
   GROUP BY R.MapID
 ) grouped
JOIN ROAD R
  on grouped.MapID = R.MapID
```

Comment: It gives the same maximum distance for all data under CityFrom and CityTo columns with respect to each MapID.